# Eagle V7 - Add via while routing without changing layer

Tags: eaglecad, via

I am using Eagle 7.6 to route a four layer board. While routing a trace, I would like to either add a via at the end of a trace or place a via mid-trace without changing the the current layer. I believe this is done with the spacebar in V8 but I don't have that.

The application is to 'pin' ground and power traces to the inner planes without a lot of futzing about. For example, all components (SMT) with a ground pad would have a little trace coming out and going straight to a via for ground.

I know I can lave the stub traces and go and drop the vias on top afterwards but this can fail if the grid changes or I am a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is hold down SHIFT while clicking the left mouse button with the ROUTE command active.  That specifically places a via, not just end the current route segment as it would without SHIFT.

Do HELP ROUTE and read the whole page carefully.

Comment: And there was me hoping to avoid falling for a RTFM trap :) I had seen the first mention of shift-click but had not seen the second mention. Gave up too soon! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Eagle 7.6 and 7.3 are similar.

What I usually do is use the Via GUI button to place a via(Looks like 3 stacked discs with the top and bottom discs green). I then right click on the via I just placed and rename the via to the same name as the trace I want it to connect to(So rename the via to the same name as your ground or power plane). Then right click properties and you can change the layer options if necessary and other options.

Alternatively there is syntax for via's which I got from the documentation:
Syntax

VIA ['signal_name'] [diameter] [shape] [layers] [flags] •..

if you just search via in eagle help you should find the command explanation.

I only really use 2 layer boards so hopefully this isn't a waste of your time.